# Can I configure scaling for and ElasticBeanstalk instance at deploy time?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can I configure scaling for and ElasticBeanstalk instance at deploy time ?

There seems to be no option to do this, so then I have to go in after it is deployed and change it in the configuration settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ebextensions then yes. You can use autoscaling related option settings in your `.ebextensions/01-scaling.config` file.

You may want to use "MinSize" and "MaxSize" option settings in the namespace "aws:autoscaling:asg".

Example config file:

```
option_settings:
   - namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
     option_name: MinSize
     value: 3
   - namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
     option_name: MaxSize
     value: 6
```

Then your options are bundled with your application and you can configure them as part of environment startup and do not have to do a second deployment.

Documentation on option settings here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html

Comment: Thankyou, I actuallymeant the autoscaling trigger but thats okay found it as aws:autoscaling:trigger on your link, however I dont understand how I can configure latency if latency is less than a second http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697570/how-do-configure-scaling-based-on-latency-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: answered the other question ... hope that helps!

Comment: Great, thanks one more thing is the name of the config file 01-scaling.config important or can it be any name.

Comment: Anything, it should have a .config extension. Files in this directory are processed in lexicographical order of their name.