# How do configure scaling based on latency in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Latency of my application deployed to AWS  Elastic Beanstalk is generally about 50 ms, I want another instance to start if average latency goes to 500ms (1/2 second). You can change the scaling Trigger in the configuration and select **Latency**, but the smallest **Unit of Measurement** is **Second** and ***Upper*** and **Lower Scale Increments** values must be an integer or percent.

So it doesn't seem possible to set a trigger as required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The properties "Lower breach scale increment" and "Upper breach scale increment" is the number of EC2 instances to add or remove.
This has to be an integer or a percentage.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html

For using subsecond latencies as triggers for scaling, set the values of UpperThreshold and LowerThreshold to "0.5" for 500 ms.
The Unit of Measurement will be Second.

Comment: It's not possible to use floating point numbers for thresholds :(